# Тень с одной стороны View

Tags: android

С помощью cardview можно установить тени вокруг View. Как установить тень только с одной стороны View, например снизу?

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что там никак нельзя сделать тень исключительно в снизу или ещё где, вы просто смысл не понимаете этих карточек, почитайте в офф. доках о material-design, там за счёт теней создаётся впечатление, что фигуры находятся на разной высоте и это ещё даёт то, что некоторые фигурки при анимации будут заезжать под другие и т.п. Если же вам просто необходима тень для эстетики, то можете взять это и вставить куда угодно

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/honeycombish_blue" />
```

Данный код в разметке экрана позволит сделать полоску в 1dp, цвет укажите серый в background и всё

Comment: Смысл тени я понимаю, просто у меня, в силу определённых обстоятельств используется LinearLayout вместо toolbar, и что бы он казался выше хочу поставить тень снизу

Comment: Точно сказать не могу, но кажется вы можете впихнуть в ToolBar свой LinearLayout и будет вам счастье